# Jenkins Pipeline throttle other jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to lock some other jobs from runing when a jenkins pipeline is running,
I've been trying to use the **exclusion-plugin** or the **throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin**
with this kind of structure :

```
 node(){
     stage "test"
     allocate('test')
     sleep time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES'
     sh "echo 'yes'" }

@NonCPS
def allocate(String resource){

  throttle = new hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty(
    maxConcurrentPerNode=1,
    maxConcurrentTotal=1,
    categories = [resource],
    throttleEnabled=true,
    throttleOption="category",
    matrixOptions=null
    )
  throttle.setOwner()
  throttle = null
  return true
}
```

But it doesn't seems to do anything...
I'm starting with the Groovy Pipeline plugin, and I'm block by the inability to throttle other jobs
Thank You for your help !

Answer (score 1):

For those who are in the same struggle,
You can use this plugin : https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin
using this branch : https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin/pull/25

I Don't know if this will be merged some day, but the MR is fully usable and can be used like :

```
echo 'Starting'
lock('my-resource-name') {
  echo 'Do something here that requires unique access to the resource'
  // any other build will wait until the one locking the resource leaves this block
}
echo 'Finish'
```

Comment: Looks like the branch got merged to master :)

Comment: Keep in mind that Lockable Resources plugin blocks job execution AFTER a node/executor has been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Throttle plugin is not supported in pipeline yet - [JENKINS-31801](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31801).

Locks and Latches plugin can help in some simple cases, though it might be deprecated in the future - [Proposed Plugin Deprecation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Proposed+Plugin+Deprecation).

Comment: Still not supported ?